# Working with for loop in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to use `for` loop in JQuery.Recently am using this

```
var os= $tr.find("td:eq(1)").html();
```

But putting inside for loop it alerts  undefined value

```
var i;
for(i=0; i<3; i++) { 
var os= $tr.find("td:eq('+i+')").html();
alert("os----------------------"+os)
}
```

Comment: What's `$tr` ? And it should be `var os= $tr.find("td:eq("+i+")").html()`.

Comment: Have you verified that the Single quotes aren't the culprit?

Answer (score 1):

may be you don't have 0th element, start loop from 1 instead of 0

```
for(i=1; i<=3; i++) { 
var os= $tr.find("td:eq("+i+")").html();
alert("os----------------------"+os)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `+i+` are characters within the `String` rather than operators and an identifier performing concatenation.

As others have mentioned, you need to match up the quotations:

```
$tr.find('td:eq('+i+')').html();
```

```
$tr.find("td:eq("+i+")").html();
```

But, you can also skip the concatenation by saving the `.find('td')` and using [`.eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```
var $cells = $tr.find("td");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var os = $cells.eq(i).html();
    alert("os----------------------"+os)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++) { 
var os= $tr.find("td:eq("+i+")").html();
alert("os----------------------"+os)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
var i;
for(i=0; i<3; i++) { 
    var os= $('tr').find("td").eq(i).html();
    alert("os----------------------"+os);
}
```